# How to import the same txt file (That updated daily) to Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a txt file that automatically do updates in a daily bases, I have to open that txt file in Excel (Delimited) and review the data.
What is the way to make Excel automatically import that specific txt file? 
Or in another words: I need to Double click on a saved Excel file and it will automatically import that specific txt file (instead of doing File->open->Browse...) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work
http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/importtext.asp?AllComments=True

In case you are getting your data from sql or any other data source , you can update the data connections in EXCEL

Just Open the excel file and hit refresh

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel do you have? If you have Excel 2016 or later, you can use the new functionality under the 'Get and Transform' tab to do this really easily. In previous versions, you can download the free Microsoft "PowerQuery" addin that was the forerunner for this.  It was previously a separate add-in called PowerQuery, and is now bulk standard in Excel.

There's many excellent walkthroughs on the internet showing this exact type of activity. Google "PowerQuery" and put a date filter on your results to show just the last year, as the functionality is constantly being updated. Add "Ken Puls" to your search term, and see what bubbles to the top. Then replace Ken "Mike Girvin" or "ExcelIsFun" and you should see like a zillion excellent tutorials on PowerQuery. Try "ExcelCampus" too, as Jon has great tutorials, as does "Chandoo". Also replace PowerQuery with "Get and Transform" and repeat those same searches.

PowerQuery is simple to learn, and lets you do stuff just by "muddling through" that would otherwise take a year or more to learn if you wanted to pick up VBA.

It acts like a user-friendly macro recorder, only unlike the macro recorder it spits out reusable code that doesn't have hard coded references in it, meaning all you need to do his hit Refresh.

Comment: Thanks @jeffreyweir, I'm using Excel 2013. It doesn't have "Get and Transform". However, I used the suggested below and it works.

Comment: Cool. FYI, I amended my answer as I incorrectly said this functionality was baked in to 2013 or later, but in fact its baked in to 2016 or later, or available as a free addin in 2010, 2013.